# Can python xlsxwriter create a pie-of-pie chart?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a working Python 3 script that creates a few pie charts in an Excel spreadsheet. Looks beautiful but I would like to be able to expand any given slice to the components that comprise the data. Excel has this capability by setting the chart type to pie-of-pie. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089531/generating-compound-pie-or-pie-of-pie-charts) post indicates that it can be done through `matplotlib` but I have already invested time in using `xlsxwriter`.

The data to be plotted are in various worksheets and are well defined. The data for each slice is essentially a sum of a varying number of rows above the cell being plotted. Does `xlsxwtiter` support this chart type and are code examples available?

`xlsxwriter` is being used to create the basic pie chart using code similar to

```
chart4=workbook.add_chart({"type": "pie"})
chart4.add_series({
  "name": "Hours by Directorate",
  "categories": directoratePieAxis,
  "values": directoratePieSeries,
  "categories_data": [],
  "values_data": [],
})
```

This works as expected but I want `type` to be `pie of pie`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't.